# How to add a line programmatically into /system/build.prop file in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to add a line into '/system/build.prop' file to enable the SMS receive functionality in my Android system.

Here goes my code :

```
Process process = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system\n");
        os.writeBytes("echo \"telephony.sms.received=true\" >> /system/build.prop\n");
        
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("BUILD_PROP", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }
            process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("BUILD_PROP", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The code executes without any error but the text **telephony.sms.received=true** doesn't append into the **build.prop** file.

**Note :** The system is **rooted** and Android version is **7.1.2**